# spring component-scan can't find packages

Tags: spring

Spring component-scan can't find packages. I think there is a problem with my project directory. I am using Intellij Idea.

My applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="" />
```

My directory;

[image]

Comment: Will you please elaborate your question, if it returns any exception means while starting server then may be jar file problem kindly add "spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE" jar and try it.If it does not find controller which annotated as @controller means then use "<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config> " context annotation config tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the way, your Maven project structure is incorrect, which is why IntelliJ shows your Java packages as regular directories. Based on the [Maven standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), you need to create `src/main/java`. So, your project structure should look like this:-

```
 src
 |- main
    |- java
       |- tr
          |- source
             |- beans
    |- resources
    |- webapps
       |- ...
```

Now, when you create `src/main/java`, IntelliJ will treat `java` directory as a regular directory (shown as an orange directory icon). To make it a source directory (blue directory icon), go to IntelliJ's Project Structure and add `java` directory as source directory. You should see something like this:-

[image]

Once `src/main/java` becomes a blue directory icon, assuming the base package you want to scan is `tr`, go to your Spring XML configuration and change this line to this:-

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="tr"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanning of classpath packages requires the presence of corresponding directory entries in the classpath. And to `autodetect` the `beans` and register the corresponding beans requires the inclusion of

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
```

where `base-package` would be a package for the classes. So in order to find beans defined in package `tr.source` and its sub-packages, you need to define `base-package` as:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="main.tr.source"/>
```

Comment: As I said It can't find "tr.source" or "src.main.tr.source" or "main.tr.source".

Comment: when you say it cannot find, is it throwing any exception while accessing the beans?

Comment: I have found the solution. "main.tr.source" is not a package but directory. When I create "new package" instead of "new directory" It works. But I still don't know what is the difference between them. Thanks for your help by the way.